# How to combine two table cells in the same table row?

Tags: php, parsing, merge, domdocument, tablecell

How can I merge the `date` td/cell into the `time` td/cell?

I would like the table row to consist of 3 cells, the middle cell should read `date time`.

**My Code:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$xpath                = new DOMXPath($dom);
$table = $xpath->query("//*[@class='mytable']//tbody")->item(0);
$td = $table->getElementsbytagname("td");
```

**test.html file contents:**

```
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody><tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>time</td>
      <td>td2</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody><tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>date time</td>
      <td>td2</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is Unclear.  Is that DOM the input or the desired output?  We expect to see both.  Please edit your question.

Comment: its my php code and example table that i want to combine

Comment: This `<td colspan="2">time date</td>`?

Comment: @Dlk yes how can i do

Comment: Iterate over the rows of the table. Concatenate the contents of the first and third children, put that into the first child, and remove the third child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the tbody tr cells.  Overwrite the 3rd occurring cell's text using the 1st occurring cell' text, then delete the first cell.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3Q6JL))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody><tr>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>time</td>
      <td>td2</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//table[@class='mytable']/tbody/tr") as $tr) {
    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName("td");
    $tds->item(2)->nodeValue = $tds->item(0)->nodeValue .
                               ' ' . $tds->item(2)->nodeValue;
    $tr->removeChild($tds->item(0));
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<table class="mytable">
  <tbody><tr>

      <td>td1</td>
      <td>date time</td>
      <td>td2</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```